# Determine if a while statement should trigger or not

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm writing a function to check if two values have changed from two arduino controllers (using arduinos to control speed in a game). In my Update function I'm checking to see if a bool has flipped from true to false to determine whether a coroutine updates either player objects speed. I'm confused on where I change the bool that determines if the while statement is true or false. Does it go in the while statement? Where should I change the _lastPlayerSpeeds? How do I kick off the process to begin with? I hope my question makes sense. Thanks!

```cs
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

namespace BikeRacers
{
    public class ArduinoInputToSpeed : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public static ArduinoInputToSpeed Instance;

        [Header("Player Speeds")]
        [Range(0.000f, 5.000f)]
        public float Player1InputSpeed = 0.000f;
        [Range(0.000f, 5.000f)]
        public float Player2InputSpeed = 0.000f;

        private float _lastPlayer1Speed = 0.000f;
        private float _lastPlayer2Speed = 0.000f;

        private bool _player1SpeedChanged = false;
        private bool _player2SpeedChanged = false;

        void Awake()
        {
            if (Instance == null)
            {
                Instance = this;
                DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
            }
            else
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
        }

        void Start()
        {
            StartCoroutine(ArduinoPlayer1SpeedInput());
            StartCoroutine(ArduinoPlayer2SpeedInput());
        }

        void Update()
        {
            if (Player1InputSpeed != _lastPlayer1Speed)
            {
                _player1SpeedChanged = true;
            }
            else
            {
                _player1SpeedChanged = false;
            }

            if (Player2InputSpeed != _lastPlayer2Speed)
            {
                _player2SpeedChanged = true;
            }
            else
            {
                _player2SpeedChanged = false;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerator ArduinoPlayer1SpeedInput()
        {
            while (_player1SpeedChanged)
            {
                //Player1Follow.GetComponent<PlayerFollow>().speed = Player1Speed / SpeedAdjustmentRatio;

                Debug.Log("Player 1 Speed: " + Player1InputSpeed);

                yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
            }
        }

        public IEnumerator ArduinoPlayer2SpeedInput()
        {
            while (_player2SpeedChanged)
            {
                //Player2Follow.GetComponent<PlayerFollow>().speed = Player2Speed / SpeedAdjustmentRatio;

                Debug.Log("Player 2 Speed: " + Player2InputSpeed);

                yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to smoothly (linearly, etc) change the player's speed based on the input? Or just directly setting the speed on input change?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new and maybe my English is bad, but I have a comment about your code:

1. Create a new Player class and add event ChangeSpeed:

```
public class Player
{
    [Range(0.000f, 5.000f)]
    public float InputSpeed
    {
        get => _inputSpeed;
        set 
        {
            if(_inputSpeed == value)
                return;

            ChangeInputSpeed?.Invoke(this, new ChangeProperyEventArgs<float>(_inputSpeed, value));
            _inputSpeed = value;
        }
    }

    private float _inputSpeed = 0;

    public event EventHandler<ChangeProperyEventArgs<float>> ChangeInputSpeed;
}
```

2. Let's create a class 'ChangeProperyEventArgs' for event arguments

```
public class ChangeProperyEventArgs<TValue>: EventArgs
{
    public readonly TValue LastValue;
    public readonly TValue NewValue;
    
    public ChangeProperyEventArgs(TValue lastValue, TValue newValue)
    {
        LastValue = lastValue;
        NewValue = newValue;
    }
}
```

3. Let's put it into practice:

```
namespace BikeRacers
{
    public class ArduinoInputToSpeed : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public static ArduinoInputToSpeed Instance;

        [Header("Player Speeds")]
        private Player _firstPlayer = new Player();
        private Player _secondPlayer = new Player();

        void Awake()
        {
            if (Instance == null)
            {
                Instance = this;
                DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
            }
            else
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
        }

        void Start()
        {
            _firstPlayer.ChangeInputSpeed += Player_ChangeInputSpeed;
            _secondPlayer.ChangeInputSpeed += Player_ChangeInputSpeed;
        }

        void Player_ChangeInputSpeed(object sender, ChangeProperyEventArgs<float> e)
        {
                //Player1Follow.GetComponent<PlayerFollow>().speed = Player1Speed / SpeedAdjustmentRation
                Debug.Log("Player 1 Speed: " + e.NewValue);
                //yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But you can use this library not to invent a bicycle (phraseology):
Unirx - Reactive Extensions

Comment: Yhanks for the help, but this is beyond my comprehension. I think I need to take a step back and start understanding how events work. :)

Comment: Did you mean "re-invent the wheel"? ^^ And yeah UniRx is a nice tool (I use it a lot) but sticking to events rather than observables is an as valid approach ;)